# How does Visual Studio 2013 compile TypeScript files without node.js installed?

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

I use TypeScript with Visual Studio Code and tsc CLI with node.js installed in that environment. I always thought tsc was a javascript program so I started wondering how Visual Studio 2013 can compile ts files without node.js installed. I see tsc in Program Files as a 164KB exe file so that would explain how it works without node.js but now I wonder what that exe is. Is tsc ultimately not a javascript program?

Comment: You do realize node.js is not the only JavaScript system in the world?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`tsc.exe` requires `tschost.dll`, which contains a JavaScript runtime. Together they load `tsc.js`. It does not use node.js.

Comment: Does VS actually even use `tsc.exe`? I would imagine not, since it doesn't ever use `csc.exe` for example for C#.

Comment: Sort of. The TypeScript build task launches tsc.exe, and VS uses the TypeScript build task when you Build a TypeScript project (but not for editor features or compile-on-save).

Comment: Ahh that explains it. What runtime is that? Is it like Windows Script Host? Is that still a thing? I think, to David's point, that 'csc.exe' is analogous to 'tsc.exe' in terms of msbuild and VS. Thanks for clearing up my curiosity. Loving TypeScript and so happy for its success!